# Exponentiation of imaginary operator

Tags: complex-numbers, operator-theory, exponential-function

It is very easy to prove that if $D=\dfrac{d}{dx}$, then $(e^{nD}f)(x)=f(x+n)$ about $x=m$ in the real numbers.

**Proof:** 
$$(e^{mD}f)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{D^nf}{n!}m^n\\
\implies (e^{mD}f)(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}m^n$$
This is the Taylor expansion $f(x+m)$ about $x=m$.

Let $D=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Then, consider $(e^{-iD}f)(x)$. Is there an analog of the above equation for imaginary operators? If no, why? (My confusion lies in the fact that $f$ must have a real input and output.)

Comment: Would you mind sketching that proof, so we have a template to go off of?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Sure! I'll do it right now.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Done. Check it out now.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that it does not equal $f(x-i)$? Are you asking about convergence issues, or looking for a rigorous proof? And unfortunately I'm not really qualified to answer the question, but hopefully someone is able to help you :)

Comment: @notnotlogical I must have mentioned hat $f$ must be a real function. I'll add that now.

Comment: When you say that $f$ must be real, do you mean inputs, outputs, both? I feel like it would just equal $f(x-i)$ would it not? But as I said, this problem is a little over my head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an analogue. Just as the operator $e^{aD}$ performs a spatial translation on the position where the function is being evaluated, the operator $e^{iaD}f)$ performs a translation in momentum space on the momentum at which the function is being evaluated:

$$(e^{iaD}f)(x)=f(p+a).$$

That is to say, it shifts the Fourier transform of a function by some amount $a$ instead of shifting the function itself.

Comment: Could you provide a proof of this statement? I'm curious. I would have tried if I wasn't so busy. Thanks!